# AngularJS Templates run twice

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, controller, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS web app with Twitter Bootstrap.  The templates and controllers run twice.  I don't know why they do this.

Below is some of the code in the index.html file:

```
<html data-ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">    
<div class="container ng-view" data-ng-view></div>

...

<script>
(function (angular) {
"use strict"; // jshint ;_;
// http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-application-with-angular-js/
angular.module('app', ['filters', 'angular', 'currency'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    var _view_ = 'view/';
    $routeProvider.
        when('/app',                {templateUrl:_view_+'app/index.html',       }).
        when('/account/settings',   {templateUrl:_view_+'app/settings.html',    }).
        when('/profile/:profile_ID', {templateUrl:_view_+'app/profile.html',    controller:ProfilePageCtrl}).
        when('/discuss',            {templateUrl:_view_+'discuss/discuss.html',     controller:DiscussCtrl}).
        when('/',                   {templateUrl:_view_+'page/home.html'        }).
        when('/:page',              {templateUrl:_view_+'page.html',            controller:PageCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
})
...
```

Can anybody provide suggestions? Are the templates and controllers supposed to run twice?

2012-12-04 Update:  I found out that the templates are running twice, whether they have controllers or not.  If a template has a controller, the controller runs twice as well.

Comment: Can you please provide a http://plnkr.co/? Its hard to understand the code just by reading it.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not declaring the same controller from any of your templates using the `ngController` directive.

Comment: @Max I added to plnkr.co but I'm not sure if I did it right.  You can see it here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/z6ylRIpcNAFZF8xMxgDB   jm:  I checked and I don't think I'm declaring the same controller from any of the other templates, as you can see in my code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
<div class="container ng-view" data-ng-view></div>
```

with

```
<div class="container ng-view"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue: my controllers were being called twice and I was only declaring them in the `$routeProvider`, not using `ng-controller` at all. Turns out, I was linking to pages using:

```
<a href='#somepage'>
```

instead of

```
<a href='#/somepage'>
```

When I rewrote my links to use the `#/` at the start, it worked. I guess Angular was "redirecting" `#somepage` to `#/somepage`, but calling the controller both times.

I see you are already using `#/` at the start of your links, but you also have a `<base href="/ ">` at the top (and there's a trailing space there, too). Maybe that is confusing Angular and it is triggering some undesired redirect?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was having exactly the same issue, I was using $routeChangeStart and it was called twice, so thanks for your answer it help me to solve my issue!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is the exact issue I was facing. Works after making the change. Upvoting :)